Quantum Device Error, Device qiskit does not exist. Make sure the required plugin is installed
I'm using Google Colab, and I have installed the following packages:

tensorflow

pennylane

qiskit

qiskit_ibm_runtime

pennylane_qiskit


I restarted the runtime too, but the error is still there.
Here's my code:
# Choose a backend from the available ones
backend_name = 'ibm_brisbane'  

# Define the Quantum Device
dev = qml.device(
    'qiskit',           
    wires=n_qubits,
    backend=backend_name,
    provider=service,
    shots=1024
)

And here is the error:
DeviceError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0950305dbfbc> in <cell line: 71>()
     69 
     70 # **Define the Quantum Device**
---> 71 dev = qml.device(
     72     'qiskit',            
     73     wires=n_qubits,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pennylane/devices/device_constructor.py in device(name, *args, **kwargs)
    282         return dev
    283 
--> 284     raise qml.DeviceError(
    285         f"Device {name} does not exist. Make sure the required plugin is installed."
    286     )

DeviceError: Device qiskit does not exist. Make sure the required plugin is installed.

When I run qml.about(), I get:
Name: PennyLane
Version: 0.39.0
Summary: PennyLane is a cross-platform Python library for quantum computing, quantum machine learning, and quantum chemistry. Train a quantum computer the same way as a neural network.
Home-page: https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: appdirs, autograd, autoray, cachetools, networkx, numpy, packaging, pennylane-lightning, requests, rustworkx, scipy, toml, typing-extensions
Required-by: PennyLane-qiskit, PennyLane-Lightning

Platform info: Linux-6.1.85±x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Python version: 3.10.12
Numpy version: 1.26.4
Scipy version: 1.13.1
Installed devices:

- qiskit.aer (PennyLane-qiskit-0.40.0.dev0)
- qiskit.basicaer (PennyLane-qiskit-0.40.0.dev0)
- qiskit.basicsim (PennyLane-qiskit-0.40.0.dev0)
- qiskit.remote (PennyLane-qiskit-0.40.0.dev0)
- default.clifford (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- default.gaussian (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- default.mixed (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- default.qubit (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- default.qutrit (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- default.qutrit.mixed (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- default.tensor (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- null.qubit (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- reference.qubit (PennyLane-0.39.0)
- lightning.qubit (PennyLane-Lightning-0.39.0)

I have tried reinstalling the packages and restarting the runtime, but the error persists.
How can I resolve this error and properly initialize the 'qiskit' device in PennyLane? Is there something I'm missing in the setup?
